# What system apps can be safely removed with Titanium backup on Nexus 4?

Tags: applications, nexus-4, uninstallation, titanium-backup

Is there an official list or something? :D

I'd like to remove some of them to improve battery life, but not sure which are safe to remove

Answer (score 1):

If your real purpose is to improve battery life, you just can **freeze** them ($6 dollars spent very well for Titanium Backup). If you don't want to spend money, i think you can use [Root Uninstaller Free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rootuninstaller.free), that includes "disable" option in the free version: all you have to do is to open it and disable the ones you don't want.
it also includes backup and unistall options if you don't trust. (backups to sdcard/rootuninstaller i think)

you just have to pay attenction to the ones you remove, bacause no official list is findable: just don't uninstall or freeze the app if its name does not convince you like OPP, HTML visualizer, package installer, SIM toolkit,... and so on.

just do a complete backup of your device and, in the worst case, reset your phone.

**everything there requires ROOT access**